# how to make spec file require other package with a major version independent of the major version

Tags: dependencies, rpm, specifications, requires

to put this question in a very short way. How can I achieve something like this:

```
BuildRequires:  mylib >= 1.0.0
BuildRequires:  mylib < 2.0.0
```

on one line? I want my package to depend on any version with major version 1, but none else. I tried:

```
BuildRequires:  mylib = 1
```

but that doesn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `mylib` package includes properly versioned library files this shouldn't be necessary. Packaging your RPM should automatically pick up the version of the libraries that your application links to and should not allow installation on a system with a version of the package that has differently versioned libraries.

rpm should also pick up any versioned library symbols that your application uses which may also help prevent this from happening incorrectly.

I don't know that there is a way to get what you want in a more literal fashion.

Edit: Some links about library versioning. I haven't read the latter two and I read the first one a while ago but recall it being fairly decent (to the amount I understood it at least).

1. [Library Versioning](https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/libtool/version.html)
2. [Dissecting shared libraries](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-shlibs/index.html)
3. [Shared Libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

Comment: I never got how that versioning system of libraries worked. Am I supposed to do that work manually in the spec file? creating mylib.so.1.2.3 packaged in mylib-1.2.3.rpm and my header in mylib-devel-1.2.3.rpm? I want to make another rpm that uses only the headers for compilation but I wanted the build to file if the right headers are not present...

Comment: What are you using to compile your library? cmake? autotools? manual makefile? I don't have a good reference for library versioning offhand but essentially, yes. You define a version and use those numbers in your library object names and then version the ABI on that. See packages/libraries for `openssl 0.9.8` versus `openssl 1.0.0` for example.

Comment: Also, yes, you put the headers and the non-versioned `libmylib.so` symlink in the `-devel` package.

Comment: ok, I'm discovering the whole rpm creation etc process...I've been making quite some of them for the moment but never got my head wrapped around that versioning system. is this described in detail somewhere? Thanks for the info anyways!

Comment: Library versioning has nothing to do with RPM packages/packaging. It is a detail of shared libraries. RPM simply uses that detail in a way that helps you here.